# jCrop force cropping

Tags: jquery, image, crop, jcrop, image-size

Any idea how to force cropping, only if the image hasn't the correct size?

I'm using the jQuery jCrop plugin.
I need to force any image to be cropped, but if you click away from the cropping area, the croping were released.
I tried to do:

```
$('#cropthumb').Jcrop({
  onRelease: setSelect,
}
```

this calls the function setSelect() on any release.
and then in a function I'm setting the selection again.

```
function setSelect(){
  jcrop_api.setSelect([10,10,180,160]);
}
```

This works as I want.
But on the initial load I'm checking, if the thumbnail is allready displayd in the correct size. If the consition match I do:

```
jcrop_api.release();
jcrop_api.disable();
```

This is not working, because my initial load will then always call the setSelect() function and the already cropped image can be cropped again.

Answer (score 1):

Create an external variable which will be set by your disable code and checked by your setSelect function.

```
var isDisabled = false;

function setSelect(){
    if(!isDisabled)
        jcrop_api.setSelect([10,10,180,160]);
}
```

And in your code where you disable jCrop:

```
isDisabled = true;
jcrop_api.release();
jcrop_api.disable();
```